# How can I make the logged-In name the default option in dropdownlist box?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Experts.

When a user logs into one of our web apps, there is a dropdownlist containing the names of all of our employees.

An employee could log into the system to record his or her entries into the database.

The employee could log the entries for another employee.

So far, an employee has had to select his or her name from the dropdown list and we don't want employees typing their names, just for consistency and to preserve data integrity.

Our problem currently is how to have employee's login name become the default option in the dropdown. The employee can select another name from the list if making the entries for another empployee.

Any ideas how to accomplish this task?

Thanks alot in advance.

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim s As String
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
        txtFullName.Text = Session.Item("assignedTo").ToString

      'Initialize Connection
        s = "Select login_id, UserName from tblusers ORDER BY UserName"
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("allstringconstrng").ConnectionString
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(s, conn)

        'Open the connection
        conn.Open()

        Try

            'Execute the Login command
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            'Populate the list of Users

            txtLoginName.DataSource = reader
            txtLoginName.DataValueField = "login_id"
            txtLoginName.DataTextField = "UserName" 
            txtLoginName.DataBind()
            'Close the reader
            reader.Close()

        Finally
            'Close Connection
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

<--new code -->
        Try

```
        'Execute the Login command
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        'Populate the list of Users
        Dim currentUserName As String = ""

        While reader.Read()
            If (reader("login_id").ToString().Equals(currentUserName)) Then
                currentUserName = reader("UserName").ToString()
            End If
        End While

        txtLoginName.SelectedValue = currentUserName


        'Close the reader
        reader.Close()

    Finally
        'Close Connection
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Page.User property to get the Name and then assign it to the dropdown's selected Value on Page_Load event.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just simply select it by text after you populate the list? I assume you'll know the `login_id` once the user logs in, so you could find the username from the results of the query, like so:

**UNTESTED:**

```
string currentUserName = "";
While reader.Read()
    If (reader("login_id").ToString().Equals(currentUserLogin)) Then
        currentUserName = reader("UserName").ToString()
    End If
End While
```

And then, once the list is populated via the results, select the correct user by username.

```
txtLoginName.Items.FindByValue(UserName).Selected = true;
```

---

**Or even better yet**, since you should already know the `login_id`, you can simply select by value from the populated drop down list, like so:

```
txtLoginName.SelectedValue = login_id
```

It's worth noting that this is making a very big assumption that the `login_id` will exist in the list. You may want to perform the appropriate check first to see if the `login_id` exists before selecting.

Comment: Not getting any errors but everything I tried has not worked. I have updated my post with your code at bottom. Can you please see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to set a breakpoint and see what exactly your code is doing. Does the If statement ever become true, thus assigning a value to `currentUserName`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using forms or windows authentication, wouldn't you just use:

```
txtLoginName.Text = User.Identity.Name
```

I believe this will select it if the text is in the list and matches exactly.  Or, just use Sam's method.  But was it the User.Identity.Name that you were looking for?

Comment: @Sam, where should I use that example you showed?

Steve, I tried using that but didn't get it to work. Could it be because this is not on our intranet where it uses the AD?

Ratan, I think your suggestion is similar to that of Steve, no?

If no, any examples I can use?

Thank you guys

Comment: If you are looking to set the selected value, you could do it in the Databound event of the dropdown list.  If you are looking for the username, I guess my next question would be: how are you authenticating?  That's where your answer would be.

Comment: we are using the conventional login script.

A user is challenged with username/password. The user's info is authenticated by making a call to the db. 

I could have used session like txtLoginName.Text = Session.Item("username").ToString and this would have worked just fine but as stated earlier, if one employee is making this entry for another employee, then we don't want the name of employee to whom the entry is made to be typed. This could result to inconsistencies. We would rather that name be selected from dropdown.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it.  How about this:  after the person logs in for the first time, just write a persistent cookie containing the selected username (if it doesn't exist).   When the user logs in again, look for the cookie and if it exists, use that to set the selected item as discussed.  I'd have to look up the code to do that; I don't remember it off-hand and can't do it at the moment.  You could have a check box that would indicate that you want to remember that username or something.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry that's not what I mean.

I have done this a ton of times using classic asp but  don't know how to do it in vb.net.

Let's say that userA logs into the system, and is redirected to another page that he uses to insert records. There is a dropdown with all users' login names. What we would like to do is show the name of the logged in user, in this case, userA as the first option on the dropdown. So rather than have this line Me.txtLoginName.Items.Insert(0, "Select a user") that shows the default "select a user", it shows the username of the currently logged in user. Does this help?

Comment: I think so, but the session variable or the cookie method should work in that case.  You set the cookie/session variable on the login page, then use it to select the current user with any of the methods described earlier (sorry it took me a while to respond).  It's actually a lot easier than it is in classic ASP.

Comment: Well, I got it worked already.

txtLoginName.SelectedValue = txtLoginName.Items.FindByText(Session.Item("UsersName")).Value just below txtLoginName.BindData() and it works great.